# Cypress. If else construction

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image]

[image]

Hello. I try to write my first Cypress test, I try to use if/else construction.
And something goes wrong.
Please help me.

```
it('Step 3 - Choose language in the dropdown, available languages EN, CZ, SK, DE ', () => {
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages').click();
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-en-GB').should('exist');
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ').should('exist');
    //cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-sk-SK').should('exist');
    //cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-de-DE').should('exist');

    if( {
        cy.contains("Language").then(() => {
            cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ').click();
        });
        } else {
            cy.contains("Jazyk").then(() => {
                cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-en-GB').click();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for if ... else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#if...else_statement) on how to form a proper if statement

Answer (score 0):

Well, your syntax seems off. Try this:

```
it('Step 3 - Choose language in the dropdown, available languages EN, CZ, SK, DE ', () => {
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages').click();
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-en-GB').should('exist');
    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ').should('exist');
    //cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-sk-SK').should('exist');
    //cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-de-DE').should('exist');

    if(cy.contains("Language")) {
        cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ').click();
    } else {
        cy.contains("Jazyk").then(() => {
                cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages-option-en-GB').click();
            });
        });
```

Try this and let me know how it goes :)

As I mentioned in the comments, if you want to override the error thrownfrom `cy.contains()` you could write before this line `cy.once('uncaught:exception', () => false)`, but this is a bad practice since it might ignore another error if the `contains` passes.

In any case, conditional testing isn't recommended at all and is a bad practice. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing).

Comment: Your syntax pointer is correct, but this code will not work on cypress, since `cy.get()` fails the test if it doesn`t find the element.

Comment: Yea, I figured. You could override it with `cy.once('uncaught:exception', () => false)` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You should find out which element has the text "Language" or "Jazyk", e.g

```
cy.get('#language-prompt')   // element with id "language-prompt", for example
  .invoke('text')
  .then(prompt => {

    const option = (prompt === 'Language') 
      ? 'dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ'
      : 'dropdown-languages-option-en-GB';

    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages').click()
    cy.getByTestId(option).click();
  })
```

If you can't figure out which element or how to select it without testing the text, use jQuery OR expression,

```
cy.get(':contains("Language"), :contains("Jazyk")')   // "," separator means OR
  .invoke('text')
  .then(prompt => {

    const option = (prompt === 'Language') 
      ? 'dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ'
      : 'dropdown-languages-option-en-GB';

    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages').click()
    cy.getByTestId(option).click();
  })
```

This assumes you cannot have both words at the same time.

---

Another way is to query the dropdown control about it's value. If the dropdown is based on an `<input>` element that would be

```
cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages')
  .invoke('val')                      // text displayed in the dropdown
  .then(currentSelection => {

    const option = (currentSelection === 'English') 
      ? 'dropdown-languages-option-cs-CZ'
      : 'dropdown-languages-option-en-GB';

    cy.getByTestId('dropdown-languages').click()
    cy.getByTestId(option).click();
  })
```